# How to localize or string format a list of words with commas and conjunctions in C#?

Tags: c#, localization, string-formatting

In C# I use resource strings and `string.Format` for localization. Sometimes I need to generate a message from an arbitrarily-sized list of terms. (Example: "You must select one of Dog, Cat, or Monkey" from list ["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey"])

I can write code to produce that message, but it undermines the **flexibility** of the format strings (the ability for translators to rearrange where arguments show up in a format string) and their **clarity** (example: "You must select one of {0}") .

What better can I do in my code and resource files to avoid those drawbacks?

Example of current code:

```
// assuming all string literals are in a Resource file somewhere...

string message = string.Format(
  "You must select one of {0}.", 
  Conjoin(new []{ "Dog", "Cat", "Monkey" }));
  // produces "You must select one of Dog, Cat, or Monkey

string Conjoin(string[] items)
{
  if (items.Length == 1) return items[0];
  if (items.Length == 2) return string.Format("{0} or {1}", items[0], items[1]);
  if (items.Length >= 3)
  {
    string result = items[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < items.Length - 1; i++)
    {
      result = string.Format("{0}, {1}", result, items[i]);
    }
    result = string.Format("{0}, or {1}", result, items[items.Length - 1]);
    return result;
  }
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a low max size on the list it's easy enough to just localize the list formatters:

```
ListFormatter[1]   "{0}"
ListFormatter[2]   "{0} or {1}"
ListFormatter[3]   "{0}, {1}, or {2}"
etc...
```

To generalize it to arbitrary list sizes, a method I have used in similar situations is to have individual formatters for list sizes with irregular formatters, and then a regular formatter for everything else. That formatter could be split into three sections, a prefix, suffix, and middle repeating section. So:

```
ListFormatter[1]      "{0}"
ListFormatter[2]      "{0} or {1}"
ListFormatterNStart   "{0}, "
ListFormatterNMid     "{{0}}, "
ListFormatterNEnd     "or {{0}}"
```

For English the Prefix and Mid are the same but maybe in other languages it won't be. Note the double bracket `{{0}}` parameters, which allow you to format a formatter.

In usage you'd do something like this, where N is the list size (psuedo-code)

```
if List[N] exists
    formatter = ListFormatter[N]
else
    formatter = ListFormatterNStart
    for i = 1 to N-2
        formatter += String.Format(ListFormatterNMid,i)
    formatter += String.Format(ListFormatterNEnd, N-1)
```

Comment: I appreciate your primitive solution. Easiest to understand, translate, and apply. Also no sane application would need more than 10 of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your `Conjoin` function that's works with any size of array and it's shorter:

```
// Uses LINQ
public string Conjoin(string[] items)
{
    if (items.Length == 1)
        return string.Format("{0}", items[0]);
    else if (items.Length == 2)
        return string.Format("{0} or {1}", items[0], items[1]);

    items[items.Length - 1] = "or " + items.Last();

    return string.Join(items.Select(i => string.Format(", {0}", i)).ToArray()).TrimStart(',').TrimStart(' ');
}
```

I tried it with `Conjoin(new string[] { "Dog", "Cat", "Monkey", "Duck" })`.

Output: `Dog, Cat, Monkey, or Duck`.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, but it is a nice implementation of the function.

Comment: @stuartd I modified it.

Comment: Still doesn't help with the l10n problem, though.

Comment: Thanks! True, shorter and less "wastefully creating many strings", but less what I'm looking for because it leans on string concatenation and trimming (less flexible for translation than string.Format and format strings).

Comment: @NathanSchubkegel I updated the fuction to use `string.Format`, It uses LINQ to loop through each item.